# When I write to a CSV file in Python, it copies part of the last row and writes it to the bottom of the file

Tags: python, csv

I am saving user data to a CSV file. When I try to update user information, the info is properly updates but it also copies the last few characters of the last row, creates a new row and pastes it in.

Here is my code

(index and new index are indexes where 2 different users are in the list lines)

```
with open(filename,'r+',newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    lines = list(reader)


with open(filename,'r+',newline='') as f:

    writer = csv.writer(f)
    lines[index][3]= inv
    lines[index][2] = money

    lines[newindex][2] = sellermoney
    lines[newindex][8] = shopitems
    writer.writerows(lines)

    f.close()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `w` mode when writing the file, so it will remove the old contents.

Comment: Otherwise, if what you write is shorter than the old file, it leaves the old end of the file.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of your `open` function's `mode` misuse.

`r+` updates the file contents. So, the former content will remain if the new content size is smaller.

So, `w` should be used in your case.

To learn more about [the open Function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)